# SQL - Locating closest value in a set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains the percentiles from a reference data set.

```
CREATE TABLE [Core].[RiskFactor](
[SpecialtyCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[RiskCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Percentile] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[RiskFactor] [numeric](5, 4) NOT NULL
)
```

Each combination of SpecialtyCode and RiskCategoryId will have 101 rows, for percentiles 0 to 100.
I considered having 101 columns instead, but I think rows will be best - however, I am open to using columns if that proves superior.

This table will be used as part of a scoring methodology, looking up the closest percentile for a test subject.  For example, I will arrive at some amount for the test subject, then want to see which RiskFactor is closest to my amount (for a given SpecialtyCode and RiskCategoryId).  Once I have located the closest value, I will then use the percentile rank in the scoring calculations.

My best idea so far has been to use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Percentile], ([RiskFactor] - @SubjectRiskFactor) AS Delta
FROM [RiskBenchmark].[Core].[RiskFactor]
WHERE [SpecialtyCode] = @SpecialtyCode
AND [RiskCategoryId] = @RiskCategoryId
AND ([RiskFactor] - @SubjectRiskFactor) >= 0
ORDER BY ([RiskFactor] - @SubjectRiskFactor)
```

but I have a feeling there is a function I haven't considered (I did think of BETWEEN and MIN and discarded them quickly).

Comment: Well, it looks like you answered your own question by providing the working code which solves the problem. So what is actually the question? Are you asking if this is a good solution? Yes, it is, except that `abs()` of the subtraction would probably be relevant. Are there better approaches? I can't think of any: yours is good, readable and straightforward.

Comment: Yeah. I don't see an actual question here.

Comment: I included my code as I think it's incumbent upon the poster to try something.  I wasn't satisfied with the approach (the TOP 1 bothers me), so thought I'd see if there was a better method.  Looks like I got hungry at the end and forgot to actually ask that <g>  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Scott: why does `top 1` bother you? If you're concerned about performance, does the execution plan actually shows you that  the `order by` is the actual bottleneck?

Comment: @MainMa: I was raised by a grumpy DBA who taught that TOP 1 was a hack and there was always a better way to frame the query to get the right row.  The execution plan looks fine and it executes very quickly.  Thanks.

Comment: @Scott: well, since the DBA told that there is a better way, he would probably be glad to tell you what he has in mind, so ask him for clarification. By the way, I would be interested to know what is his suggested approach, so feel free to answer your own question (and you can mark it as an answer).

Comment: You could use MIN(delta) group by..

Comment: To remove the top 1, but its not really helpfull unless you are using this as a subquery

Comment: There is an alternative that has a sub-query with a MIN() but what you've posted is perfectly acceptable. A few observations, though: a) it's not recommended to include the database name since this makes moving between environments (dev/ test/ prod) more difficult; b) the `>= 0` means you're not finding the closest but the next highest; c) `AND ([RiskFactor] - @SubjectRiskFactor) >= 0` could be rephrased as `AND [RiskFactor] >= @SubjectRiskFactor` which would make it SARGABLE; d) TOP can be beneficial http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/how-and-why-does-top-impact-an-execution-plan

Comment: e) this assumes `RiskFactor` is monotonic within the other two keys.